# Change gnome disk utility to use binary units

Tags: gnome3, gnome-disks

When I open gnome disk utility it shows disk capacities in decimal. Is there a way to make it so that it displays disk sizes in binary? I'm running gnome 3.22.1 on Debian sid.

Comment: Not unless you patch the source code afaik (basically you have to [reverse this patch](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-disk-utility/commit/src?id=9f4bd12b3842d1bc30d458de378517de8941ce95))

Comment: @don_crissti Dammit...well that's a chore. The one thing I hate about gnome is it seems like a lot of settings don't exist or you have to use dconf to get at it.

Comment: @don_crissti alright will do. Why are people moving to units of 10? Computers are base 2 machines by nature. It pisses me off as it is having disks sold in base 10. I think it's dumb.

Comment: @don_crissti it's Linux? Is there anyone using it who doesn't know base 2?

Comment: @don_crissti yep I totally get that. Except windows, at least windows 7, measures in base 2 anyway. Not 10